Upgrading a .NET 7 test application to .NET 8 using browserstack results with JSOn issues
I updated all the packages appium and a Microsoft JSon nuget package and the BrowserStack package and went through the Upgrade Assistant and after that I get this - I have no Idea how to fix it and I am not too familiar with JSOn to understand what it needs:

System.NotSupportedException: JsonTypeInfo metadata for type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' was not provided by TypeInfoResolver of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.CommandJsonSerializerContext'. If using source generation, ensure that all root types passed to the serializer have been annotated with 'JsonSerializableAttribute', along with any types that might be serialized polymorphically. The unsupported member type is located on type 'System.Object'. Path: $.
System.NotSupportedException : JsonTypeInfo metadata for type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' was not provided by TypeInfoResolver of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.CommandJsonSerializerContext'. If using source generation, ensure that all root types passed to the serializer have been annotated with 'JsonSerializableAttribute', along with any types that might be serialized polymorphically.


It looks like this issue is related to Appium.Webdriver 6.0.1 it appears it could also be Selenium that goes from 25 to 26. Not sure how to fix it. I reverted back to  a pervious version for now.
